# Parser ASP page with PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing

With this code

```
<?php
 /*GET ALL LINKS FROM http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp*/ 
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.codacons.it/rassegna_quest.asp?idSez=14'); 
preg_match_all("/<a.*>(.*?)<\/a>/", $page, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
echo "All links : <br/>"; 
foreach($matches as $match){ 
    echo $match[1]."<br/>"; 
} 
?>
```

But it not parse this link from this page http://www.codacons.it/rassegna_quest.asp?idSez=14

'Questionario': OFFICINE PER L'ASSISTENZA E MANUTENZIONI VEICOLI
'Questionario': RIVENDITORE AUTO USATE 
'Questionario': RACCOLTA RICICLATA DEI RIFIUTI DI IMBALLAGGI IN PLASTICA 
'Questionario': DONNE E POLITICA

Why ???

Comment: Because you are doing it wrong.

Comment: NO REGEX HTML! REGEX HTML BAD! [MONGO SMASH](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28khv-BydeY)!

Comment: That is HTML, not ASP. The HTML might be generated by ASP, but you never see the ASP so thinking about it is just a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I should start with the typical "[Don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)". This would be easy with XPath (using [DOMXpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $dom_xpath->evaluate("//a");
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    print $entry->nodeValue;
}
```

But if you must go the regex route, I imagine the greedy star `.*` is the source of your problems. Try this:

```
preg_match_all("@<a[^>]+>(.+?)</a>@/", $page, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Comment: How can I take and example for DOMXpath ?

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, whatever...

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.codacons.it/rassegna_quest.asp?idSez=14');
preg_match_all('#<a href="articolo(.*?)" title="Dettaglio notizia">(.*?)</a>#is', $page, $matches);

$count = count($matches[1]);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    echo '<a href="articolo'.$matches[1][$i].'">'.trim(strip_tags(preg_replace('#(\s){2,}#is', '', $matches[2][$i]))).'</a>'; 
}
```

Result:

```
<a href="articolo.asp?idInfo=138400&amp;id=">'Questionario':OFFICINE PER L'ASSISTENZA E MANUTENZIONI VEICOLI</a>
<a href="articolo.asp?idInfo=138437&amp;id=">'Questionario':RIVENDITORE AUTO USATE</a>
<a href="articolo.asp?idInfo=127900&amp;id=">'Questionario':RACCOLTA RICICLATA DEI RIFIUTI DI IMBALLAGGI IN PLASTICA</a>
<a href="articolo.asp?idInfo=138861&amp;id=">'Questionario':DONNE E POLITICA</a>
```